# ¿Se pueden aplicar dos estilos al mismo dataframe?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, style

estoy trabajando con python 3.8 y necesito sacar un un excel que tenga varios estilos aplicados.
Tengo la siguiente función que "pinta" toda la fila si se encuentra un determinado valor:

```
def highlight_row_content(column, value, color):
    cont_val = column == value
    return ['background-color:' + color if cont_val.any() else '' for v in cont_val]
```

La cosa es que me gustaría aplicar varias veces esta función pero con valores y colores distintos, algo así:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('salida.xlsx')
tabla1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='hoja1')

tabla2.style.apply(highlight_row_content, value="Valor1", color='red', axis=1).to_excel(writer, sheet_name='hoja2', index=False)
tabla2.style.apply(highlight_row_content, value="Valor2", color='#blue', axis=1).to_excel(writer, sheet_name='hoja2', index=False)
```

Lo malo es que se sobreescriben, es decir, que el resultado final sólo tiene aplicado la 2a función. ¿Hay alguna forma de arreglarlo? ¿O se tiene que modificar la función?

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes aplicar los estilos de forma encadenada y renderizar al final:

```
import pandas as pd


def highlight_row_content(column, value, color):
    cont_val = column == value
    return [f'background-color: {color}' if cont_val.any() else '' for v in cont_val]

tabla1 = pd.DataFrame({"highlight_row_content": ("hola",
                                                  "foo",
                                                  "bar")}
                      )

with pd.ExcelWriter('salida.xlsx') as writer:
    tabla1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='hoja1')

    (tabla1.style.apply(highlight_row_content, value="hola", color='red', axis=1)
                 .apply(highlight_row_content, value="foo", color='blue', axis=1)
    ).to_excel(writer, sheet_name='hoja2', index=False)
```

o si quisieras una hoja con cada estilo:

```
import pandas as pd


def highlight_row_content(column, value, color):
    cont_val = column == value
    return [f'background-color: {color}' if cont_val.any() else '' for v in cont_val]

tabla1 = pd.DataFrame({"highlight_row_content": ("hola",
                                                  "foo",
                                                  "bar")}
                      )

with pd.ExcelWriter('salida.xlsx') as writer:
    tabla1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='hoja1')

    style_table1 = tabla1.style.apply(
        highlight_row_content, value="hola", color='red', axis=1
        )
    style_table1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='hoja2', index=False)

    style_table2 = style_table1.apply(
        highlight_row_content, value="foo", color='blue', axis=1
        )
    style_table2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='hoja3', index=False)
```